# Wait for Data Before Rendering View in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular 5 and was able to create view with access to service methods using subscribe but encounter problem in delay in render. The user see first "undefined" string and after 0.5 sec it change to the correct value.

Here is the .ts file for the component:

```
 public trips: Trip[];
  public numberOfUsers : Map<string, number> = new Map<string, number>();

  constructor(private tripService: TripService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.getTrips();
  }

  getTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTripForMe().subscribe(
      data => { this.trips = data;},
      err => console.error(err),
      () => this.initNumberOfUsers()
    );
  }

  initNumberOfUsers() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.trips.length; i++) {
      let count;
      this.tripService.getNumberOfUsers().subscribe(
        data => { count = data},
        err => console.error(err),
        () => this.numberOfUsers.set(this.trips[i].id, count)
      );


      ;
    }
  }

  getNumberOfUsers(data) {
    return this.numberOfUsers.get(data.id);
  }
```

The method initNumberOfUsers is called after the first subscribe finish which is good, but the getNumberOfUsers(data) called probably before and get "undefined".

Here is the relevant part from the template ("data" is current value of a ngFor loop):

```
<span [innerText]="getNumberOfUsers(data)"></span>
```

Is there a way to make sure that both subscribe methods are sequentially finalized before rendering ?

**UPDATE**

I was able to create a resolver and the concole show the object but, I have difficulties to pass the data to the component.

**Reolver code:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Trip} from ....
import { TripService } from .....
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class TripsResolve implements Resolve<Trip[]> {

   public trips: Trip[];

   constructor(private service: TripService) {}

   resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
           state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     this.service.getTrips().subscribe(
        data => { this.trips = data },
        err => console.error(err),
        () => console.log(this.trips)
      );
      return this.trips;
   }
}
```

**From route**

```
resolve: {
         trips: TripsResolve
      }
```

**From module**

```
providers: [
        ...
        TripsResolve,
        ...
```

**Data is not pass/not avilavle in the component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Trip } from ...
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: ...
  templateUrl: ...
  styleUrls: ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    public trips: Trip[];

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.forEach(data => {
            this.trips = data.trips;
            console.log(this.trips);  //can't see it
       });

    } 
}
```

Any idea how can I access/retrieve the data in the component ?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I have faced similar issues when I'm dealing with data through API calls

I have tried two solutions

One is using ***ngIf**

The DOM will populate only when the data is ready.

```
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">Text to show</div>
```

Another one is using **resolver**, before rendering view itself it will prepare the data. But sometimes resolver will keep your screen as blank if data loads takes too much time.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroDetailResolve implements Resolve {
    constructor(private heroService: HeroService, private router: Router) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Promise | boolean {
        let id = +route.params['id'];
        return this.heroService.getHero(id).then(hero => {
            if (hero) {
                return hero;
            } else { // id not found
                this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So you have two options now.

I would recommend ***ngIf.** While loading of data is in progress, display some loader gif or some message to let the user know that something happening in the background.

Comment: what is isLoaded exactly?

Comment: We will be having a user-defined flag variable to maintain the status of the API call

Comment: Thanks for this. I was having the same problem

Comment: @marknt15 happy that you're problem has been resolved

Answer (score 3):

Check out resolvers in Angular.

Here is a link:
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Much like guards, they run before the component is fully created and prevent you from having to have if/else logic in your template for waits while loading.

If you don't want to use a resolver, you can also do something like:

```
<span *ngIf="myVariable; else stillLoading" [innerText]="getNumberOfUsers(data)"></span>

<ng-template #stillLoading><p>Loading...</p></ng-template>
```

`myVariable` would be whatever you want to be defined before you render the `<span>` tag.  I just didn't want to look that closely into your map :)

The choice on whether to use a resolver or if/else in templates depends on what you want your UX to be like.  There's probably other reasons too, but that one comes to mind first.

Comment: Generally I agree with this answer, however due to the use case I would recommend ngShow over ngIf. As ngIf will not post the tag to the DOM, which could cause un-desirable ssues with layout. ngShow will apply and reserve the expected "real estate" on the DOM for the hidden tag, but will only populate once the data is ready. That said, I generally recommend ngIf for many cases, but it sounds like the render of this display is important so it may likely be better to simply hide the span temporarily.

Comment: I have to admit.. i didn't read the question that closely... getting tired and decompressing with some typescript gimmes... however, using `ngIf` doesn't HAVE to affect the layout in a negative way if you use `ngIf/Else` and render things based on the state of the data...

Comment: Sure, this is correct, but then you potentially have to manage the DOM render in a cascade fashion to accommodate for the missing parts. ngShow might be a little cleaner in that regard, but indeed either approach could work.

Comment: I can agree with ngShow being easier to handle the layout in some cases...but much tougher to handle nulls.  Tradeoff I suppose.  I think that I personally use ngIf 95/100 times... maybe I need to re-evaluate when I use what when.

Comment: I agree, ngIf 90% of the time also. Unless layout (sometimes maintenance) and presentation is a high priority. Whichever way he goes the local should be initialized. Unless it's a complex object, null/undefined shouldn't be a consideration in your template. Also in the case of complex types.... Safe navigation operator FTW!!! myComplexType?.myPotentiallyNullObject?.myPotentiallyNullObjectsPotentiallyNullProperty. *cheers*

Comment: Note: Even with the above example it would be critical for myComplexType to be initialized. Not initializing these things negates a vast portion of the compile/transpile time benefit that TypeScript affords us.

Comment: This link recommends to use route information in your service. I don't want to do that. I don't think services should know anything about routes. I want to solve this in the component or template.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the two subscriptions using a mergeMap. This way they will emit once the last sub's completed method is triggered.

Though in your case you may find it easier to simply initialize the numberOfUsers to null. Then in your template use ng-show to only display the span when numberOfUsers is not null.

ex:

```
<div *ngShow="numberOfUsers">
  <span [innerText]="getNumberOfUsers(data)"></span>
</div>
```

*cheers*

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think `ngShow` renders the element and just effectively hides it... still throwing null pointers... don't think that would work

Comment: You are correct, ngShow still applies the tag to the DOM. However based on the use case described this would be the ideal approach. It does not sound as if we are getting errors here, but rather just getting undesirable results during transclusion due to the data not being ready.

Comment: All that said, either way will work, but based on what is attempted to be accomplished I would recommend ngShow in this scenario.

Comment: see my reply to your comment in my answer :)

Comment: Between these two he will have some options, hopefully he can play with them and find what works best. Another option for him would be putting it on the (activated) route as you eluded, input, or even more intricate usage of the NG hooks , but these two suggestions will probably be the easiest.